# Installing El Capitan from a bootable DVD

Tags: startup, efi, bootable-disk

I have El Capitan on a bootable DVD. I restart my Mac and hold the option key until the disks come up and I choose EFI Boot (name of the disk is different than what it shows at the time of booting). DVD-ROM starts like a jet and a progress bar pops up. It goes all the way to very close to the end and then DVD-ROM stops and no more progress. I never have installed any OS X and now I am wondering if such a thing is possible at all. I checked the Boot ROM version and upgraded to the last version that matches my mac 8.1.

My question obviously is what should I do?

Comment: A "mac 8.1" doesn't exist. Please add a proper identifier. Also add your current system version. Why don't you just download El Cap from the App Store and install it afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

I've created bootable DVDs (DVD+R DL, specifically) for Mavericks, Yosemite, and El Capitan, and used them without any problems to install on various MacBook Pros. Thus, the OS X installer can't require write access to the installer's volume (as of 10.11.x anyway). Creating an El Capitan installation DVD is slightly different than previous, but a user 'tywebb13' on MacRumors is who I've followed each time I've created these DVD installers. He's posted the Terminal commands (including short explanations for each) to create a bootable El Capitan DVD (or just the ISO if you skip the last command).

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/el-capitan-bootable-dvd.1923931/page-2#post-22407115

NOTE: Some of the posts in that thread refer to installing them in virtual machines, which adds confusion. But 'tywebb13' is consistently focused on optical media installers for actual Apple hardware, and I've always followed his instructions to success.